# is it good practice if i append all the html data through ajax response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i wanted to ask i am running a ajax function that loads all the data to my html. now all the data shows itself but i have done this by appending all the data as their are so many post i need to create a loop that shows all the post in a loop

here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(e){

    // grab the scroll amount and the window height
       loadmore();
       // get_recieve_friend_requests();
       // get_sent_friend_requests();
    });

 function loadmore(){
          var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');
         //alert(lastID);

              jQuery.ajax({
                  type:'POST',

                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
                   data: {id:  lastID },
                      dataType: 'json', 


                  beforeSend:function(data){
                      $('.load-more').show();
                  },
                  success:function(data){

                         var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                         var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);



                         if (json=="") {
                          $("#bottom").append('<div class="btn btn-default col-md-6" >'+'No More Results'+'</div>');
                          $("#Load_more_data").hide()

                         }else{
                           $postID=json[json.length-1].id;

              $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $postID);

                $.each(json, function (key, data) {
   $post_id=data.id;

   var post_id=data.id;
     // $('.post_id_value').attr('post_id', $post_id);
    var post_status=data.status;
     var status_image=data.status_image;
    var multimage=data.multimage;


                             if(!post_status=="" && !status_image==""){
                               $("#status_data").append('<input type="text" value="'+ post_id+'" class="post_id_value"> <div class="col-md-6 postdata"><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname;?></a><div class="weshare_user_status">'+post_status+'</div><div class="weshare_user_singleimage"><img style="height:300px; width:400px;" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads'); ?>/'+status_image+'"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a  onclick="like();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li></ul></div></div></div>');
                             }else{

                             }

                              if(!post_status=="" && status_image==""){
                               $("#status_data").append('<input type="text" value="'+ post_id+'" class="post_id_value"><div class="col-md-6 postdata" ><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname;?></a><div class="weshare_user_status">'+post_status+'</div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a  onclick="like();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li></ul></div></div></div>');
                             }else{

                             }


                             if (multimage=="") {

                             }
                              else{
                               $("#status_data").append('<input type="text" value="'+ post_id+'" class="post_id_value"><div class="col-md-6 postdata" ><a ><?php echo img($user_image); ?></a><a class="weshare_user_name text-font"><?php echo $uname; echo " "; echo $lname; ?></a><div class="weshare_user_multimage"><img style="height:300px; width:400px;" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads'); ?>/'+multimage+'"></div><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><ul class="list-inline"><li><a  onclick="like();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like</a></li><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Comment</a></li><li><a ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Share</a></li></ul></div></div></div>');
                              }                              

                    });
                  }
              }
            });
          }
                  function like()
          {
              var Post_id = $('.post_id_value').attr('value');
              var User_id = $('.id_data').attr('value');
              alert(Post_id);
                jQuery.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  url:'<?php echo base_url("user/post_likes"); ?>',
                  data: {Post_id:  Post_id,User_id:User_id},
                  dataType: 'json', 
                  success:function(data)
                  {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert();
                  }
          });
              }

  </script>
```

see that i have created all the div in a response is it possible to return all these values so that i can accesss them in a loop using $.each as there are 500 posts so what can i do  can you tell me?

when i alert 'json' it shows me this look at the image [image: json value when alert]

Comment: what value does `var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);` return?

Comment: look at the edited code

Comment: For the sake of SEO, you will probably want some static prerendered pages and use async ajax while browsing the website without reloading the whole pages and pushing browser history and rewrite url with JS. (If it's non-public content, it shouldn't matter)
**PS: to your title question.**  - It **IS** good practice to render large portion of HTML dynamically via ajax - **If it's done right though.**

Comment: i wanted to ask if there was some other way to send 'post_Status' and these values in a loop so that other functions can be accessed @AdamK.

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal can you elaborate a little more? I am not sure what you have in mind.

Comment: what i wanted to do was send the post_status and post_image in a loop outside the ajax function right now i am sppending them but would it be possible to return or send these values outside without the use of append and also in a loop @AdamK.

Comment: @HimanshuGoyal I am not sure if i still understand... You can create an  object in global scope outside the function before triggering the ajax and then fill the object with data from ajax, maybe in format like `{post_id:{"post_status":"Hello World","status_image":"//domain.com/urlToImage.jpg"}}` - when the filling of the object is done, you can trigger next functions, that will work with the data. - is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

**Access global scope javascript object filled by ajax.**

Like this? (it is not exact solution, just for an inspiration)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var posts={};
    $(window).load(function(e){
       ajax();
    }
    function ajax(){
       //... the ajax stuff
       success:function(ajaxData){
          //... json stringify and parse object
          $.each(json, function (key, data){//fill the global scope object with received data to be accessible outside the ajax function
              posts.push({data.post_id:{"post_status":data.post_status, "status_image":data.status_image}});
          }
       }
    }
</script>
```